# Shifting an image down

Tags: visualforce, css, commandbutton, images, commandlink

I have a search bar along with a search and clear button. What I would like is for the clear button to be centered with the search button. I have tried using padding-top on the image as well as it's commandlink to no avail.

Here is the code for it:

```
<apex:form id="searchBarForm">
  <apex:inputText value="{!nameSearch}" onkeypress="executeSearchAfterEnter(event)" />
  <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" rerender="EntirePage" value="{!$Label.Search}"/> 
  <apex:commandLink action="{!clearSearchBar}" reRender="EntirePage" rendered="{!nameSearch != null}">
    <apex:image value="{!$Resource.clearButton}" height="18px" width="18px"/>
  </apex:commandLink>
</apex:form>
```

And here is what it looks like on the page:

[image]

As you can see the clear button is a bit higher than the search button. I would like to bring it down a bit so that it looks aligned with the button that it is next to.

Comment: This is more of a css question so may be stackoverflow be better community to ask this question?

Comment: While it's true that CSS would be needed, I don't think this question necessarily needs to be answered elsewhere. The code, being salesforce-specific, would get better attention here, and would generally be useful to other salesforce developers. Answer on.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using the vertical-align property for the image component. I did this because the visual force page is an iframe that will be allocated a certain height so I feel comfortable using a specific number of pixels to lower the button so that it is centered.